# Efficient pairwise comparison between an row and column array

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Given a row vector `a = np.array([1, 2, 3])` and a column vector `b = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])` we can compare all elements one by one by executing `c = a==b` which returns

```
>>> c
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True]])
```

However, when the number of elements is very large this demands a lot of memory. Is it possible use the sparse matrices `a` and `b` below and compute a sparse `c` matrix efficiently?

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
data = np.array([1, 2, 3])
row = np.array([0, 1, 2])
col = np.array([0, 0, 0])

a = csr_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 1))
b = csr_matrix((data, (col, row)), shape=(1, 3))
```

Comment: what are the real dimensions you are working with ? is it always (x,1) and (1,x) or is there like (x,3) and (5,x) ?

Comment: No sparse won't help, even if there are few matches.

Comment: @AhmedAEK it is always a comparison between (x, 1) and (1, x).

Comment: @hpaulj any other suggestions except using sparse matrices are very welcome.

Comment: `c = a.flatten()==b.flatten()` will return an one by one comparison. I need a one to all comparison. That is, for the `a` vector, the first element of `a` with all elements of `b`,  the second element of `a` with all elements of `b` and so on.  `c` represents this information.

Comment: ok i figured, that one out, i don't think python has this functionality anywhere, i think you'll have to write python code or a C++ extension for it, but what is the expected output ? are you expecting a matrix of certain format like a csr matrix ? or a list of tuples will be acceptable ?

Comment: @AhmedAEK your answer I think was fine with the csr matrix output. Was something wrong? Could you please recover it?

Comment: it was not doing comparison equality, it's hard to find any brain cells today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed up a==b you can use `numexpr.evaluate('a==b')`, however this wont eliminate the memory burden.

Instead, you can store the indices of where a==b is True:

```
In [5]: import numexpr

In [6]: import numpy as np

In [7]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3,4])

In [8]: b = np.array([[1], [3], [5]])

In [9]: np.where(numexpr.evaluate('a==b'))  # this consumes the memory
Out[9]: (array([0, 1]), array([0, 2]))  # note, this is rows, cols

In [10]: for col,aval in enumerate(a):  # this will be a lighter memory burdern
    ...:     rows = np.where(aval==b)[0]
    ...:     if not rows.size:
    ...:         continue
    ...:     for row in rows:
    ...:         print (row, col)
    ...: 
0 0
1 2
```

For clarity:

```
In [14]: a==b
Out[14]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```